# Android Architecture Component: Observer not called in JUnit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, architecture

Looking at this example: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample
I've implemented the same pattern in one of my side projects however, I'm facing difficulties getting tests to work as expected.

I'm trying to test my one of my repository classes. The test checks if the repository fetches data from the api and if the value of the observer changes.

Here is the test class

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class TimelineRepositoryTest {

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private DatabaseDao databaseDao;
    private ApiService apiService;
    private TimelineRepository timelineRepository;

    @Rule
    public InstantTaskExecutorRule instantExecutorRule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        sharedPreferences = mock(SharedPreferences.class);
        databaseDao = mock(DatabaseDao.class);
        apiService = mock(ApiService.class);
        timelineRepository = new TimelineRepository(apiService, sharedPreferences, databaseDao);
        timelineRepository.appExecutors = new InstantAppExecutors();
    }

    @Test
    public void fetchTimelineWithForceFetch() {
        TimelineResponse timelineResponse = new TimelineResponse();
        when(sharedPreferences.getLong(PreferenceUtils.PREFERENCE_LAST_TIMELINE_REFRESH, 0)).thenReturn(0L);
        when(apiService.retrieveTimeline()).thenReturn(ApiUtil.successCall(timelineResponse));

        MutableLiveData<List<Event>> dbData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        when(databaseDao.loadEvents()).thenReturn(dbData);
        Observer observer = mock(Observer.class);

        timelineRepository.getTimelineEvents().observeForever(observer);


        verify(observer).onChanged(Resource.loading(null));
        verify(observer).onChanged(Resource.success(new ArrayList<Event>());
    }
}
```

Also, here is the actual repository class:

```
public class TimelineRepository {

    @Inject AppExecutors appExecutors;
    @Inject @Named("timelineRefreshDurationInMillis") long timelineRefreshDurationInMillis;

    private final DatabaseDao databaseDao;
    private final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private final ApiService apiService;

    public TimelineRepository(ApiService apiService, SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, DatabaseDao databaseDao) {
        this.apiService = apiService;
        this.sharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;
        this.databaseDao = databaseDao;
    }

    public LiveData<Resource<List<Event>>> getTimelineEvents() {
        return new NetworkBoundResource<List<Event>, TimelineResponse>(appExecutors) {
            @Override
            protected void saveCallResult(@NonNull TimelineResponse timelineResponse) {
                if (timelineResponse.events != null) {
                    databaseDao.saveEvents(timelineResponse.events);
                }
                PreferenceUtils.storeLastTimelineRefreshTimeInMillis(sharedPreferences, System.currentTimeMillis());
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean shouldFetch(@Nullable List<Event> data) {
                return System.currentTimeMillis() - PreferenceUtils.getLastTimelineRefreshTimeInMillis(sharedPreferences) > timelineRefreshDurationInMillis;
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            protected LiveData<List<Event>> loadFromDb() {
                return databaseDao.loadEvents();
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            protected LiveData<ApiResponse<TimelineResponse>> createCall() {
                return apiService.retrieveTimeline();
            }
        }.getAsLiveData();
    }
}
```

I want to use the test to check if the mocked observer is called multiple times with different values. However, the test says that it is only called one with the loading argument.

After some debugging it seems like the NetworkBoundResource's https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.java#L48 observer registered in the constructor is not called.

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Have you found a solution on this?